# Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: localhost:9003

Tags: php, apache, visual-studio-code, xampp, xdebug

My php.ini configuration:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"   
xdebug.mode = debug 
xdebug.remote_autostart = on
xdebug.profiler_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = on
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/xampp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9003
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_log="c:/xampp/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

My launch.json configuration:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9003
        }
        

    ]
}
```

but i am still getting this error in error.log:

```
[php:notice] [pid 9388:tid 1840] [client ::1:63322] Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(, referer: http://localhost/online-store/admin/types/insert-types.php
```

First I used the port 9000 but it didn't work, then I tried changing the port in php.ini and launch.json to 9003 same as the port in error log but still nothing is happening and XDebug is not working and not stopping on breakpoints.

Comment: Based on your error message you have Xdebug **v3** but your config uses **v2** parameter names & values. Check the following link and update accordingly: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide ALSO: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw

Comment: Did you click `Start Debugging`? I'd need to see the vscode/extension log to be sure that the extension is actually listening on port 9003. As pointed out by @LazyOne a bunch of configuration directives in you php.ini file are for Xdebug 2. But I don't think this is the main issue here.

Answer (score 30):

I also encountered with such an error after updting my Xdebug library to 3+ version.

What I found out is that new setting `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` configures Xdebug to establish a connection on every request.

Meanwhile the official [doc](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#start_with_request) offers to use `xdebug.start_with_request = trigger` in order to connect Xdebug only if the need for it was explicitly indicated. In this case I can start step debugging process with passing an extra key via GET parameters, for example `http://localhost/?XDEBUG_TRIGGER=1`, but this is inconvenient for me, all I want is press F5 within my VSCode to start debugging as I always did.

So my solution is the following. I left `start_with_request = yes` and turned off most of Xdebug notifications by passing `xdebug.log_level = 0`. Then i override `log_level` within `launch.json` file to enable all warnings but only within debugging session.

**php.ini**:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = php_xdebug-3.0.4-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll
xdebug.mode = debug,develop
xdebug.discover_client_host = yes
xdebug.log_level = 0
xdebug.log = "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/xdebug/log.txt"
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
```

**launch.json**:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "log_level=7",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Informative/Great answer regarding xdebug.

Comment: Rather than passing URL parameters, we use a browser extension called [Xdebug Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc). This works great. Alternatively you can set a cookie (which is what Xdebug Helper does, I believe) or an environment variable. Then you can set `start_with_request=trigger` and avoid that janky logging setup.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue with PHP8. In my case, it was just the XDebug version suggested by their own wizard.
I use this version and it works just fine.
3.0.0-8.0-vs16

Comment: Same here: I reinstalled my XAMPP environment and downloaded the suggested XDebug version (3.2.0.11) which lead me to this error. I downloaded the 3.0.4-vs16 version I used a couple years ago and it works like a charm. I don't know if the intermediate versions work but the XDebug wizard isn't 100% reliable.

Answer (score 1):

launch.json:

```
       {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",  
            "type": "php",  
            "request": "launch",  
            "port": 9003,  
            "hostname": "localhost",  
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}/www/"
            },
        },
```

change pathmappings according to your requirements and the most important is hostname. after i added that, it worked

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message after my computer started to use a different IP address. The reason why the change happened was that after I disconnected it from the ethernet cable, it connected to the wifi router, which meant a new IP address.

The solution was to change the `/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini` file. I modified the line `xdebug.client_host=192.168.1.110` to `xdebug.client_host=192.168.1.107` where the new value comes from the output of the `ipconfig` command.