# Getting "Debug session was finished without being paused" and no stop in execution when using Xdebug in PhpStorm

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to debug an issue in my web application using Xdebug 3.0 and PhpStorm 2021.1. I am set up on WSL2 using Debian 10 in which I installed Xdebug and used the following settings in `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so                                                                                 xdebug.session=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=XXX.XX.XXX.X
xdebug.client_port=9000
xdebug.max_nestling_level=10000
xdebug.log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey=xdebug
```

I am using Symfony 5.3 and when I was using `symfony server:log` to stream the logs I was getting multiple error messages of `Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms`, but setting breakpoints would stop my web app correctly. After attempting a fix for this issue I am now getting the following error within PhpStorm:

"**Debug session was finished without being paused** It may be caused by path mappings misconfiguration or not synchronized local and remote projects."

Steps I've taken:

- Set `xdebug.start_with_request=trigger` in 20-xdebug.ini according to [Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: localhost:9003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67556940/xdebug-step-debug-time-out-connecting-to-debugging-client-waited-200-ms-tr) which successfully fixed the time-out warning message
- Added breakpoints to a controller
- Enabled debugging in the Xdebug Chrome extension
- Enabled listening for PHP debug connection in PhpStorm
- Navigated to the view which should cause a hit on the breakpoint
- Execution stopped on every view (even those without a breakpoint in the controller) and the PhpStorm Debugger terminal came up with an error message `Click to set up path mappings`
- Selected the "Use path mappings" checkbox which removed the mapping error

What I was expecting:

- For the execution of my web page and controller to stop during events where the breakpoint is being hit.

The actual result:

- Every web page loads and the breakpoint doesn't stop execution (I tried additional breakpoints to be sure it wasn't an isolated issue)
- I receive the "Debug session was finished without being paused" warning in the PhpStorm Event Log.

Further steps I have taken with no success:

- Changing the trigger setting back to `xdebug.start_with_request=yes`
- Adding the absolute path on the server in the path mapping settings

Supporting content:

Event Log message
[image: Event Log message]

PhpStorm Xdebug Settings
[image: PhpStorm Xdebug Settings]

Impact of my problem:

- It's preventing me from diagnosing a CSRF issue within my web application which I need to amend to have a functional login form.

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I supplied a lot of detail in my question but it turned out to be a very simple answer... Classic!

For anyone else, all I did was invalidate the cache and restart PHPStorm

1. Go to File > Invalidate Caches...
2. Check "Clear downloaded shared indexes"
3. Click Invalidate and Restart

The result:

- Breakpoints now stop execution on the correct views

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me but the following did:

1. PHPStorm > Settings > PHP > Servers
2. Select the respective server
3. "Use path mappings" was checked for me. My setup is local so that wasn't correct. Unchecking made it detect the debug session.